# Публикация панорам на Яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем доброго времени суток! С сервисами яндекса раньше не работал, тут появилась задача сделать панораму (интерьер одной организации) и опубликовать ее на гугл стрит и на яндекс картах, с первым проблем не было, а вот по поводу яндекс карт есть вопросы. Поверхностно изучил яндекс апи, создать панораму труда не составило, думаю прилепить к карте тоже нее трудно будет, но вопрос есть ли какая то возможность опубликовать панораму именно на карту яндекс ну что бы всем было видно а не только посетителям сайта этой организации. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Напишите в https://neq4.ru они этим занимаются.

Comment: спассибо за помощь, а самому сделать никак?

Comment: Попробуйте написать в техподдержку Яндекс. Возможно, что-то поменялось, но раньше было только так.

Answer (score 0):

В настоящее время панорамы на Яндекс.Карты можно добавить самостоятельно на портале https://pano.maps.yandex.ru/

Подробная информация и требования описаны в [справке](https://yandex.ru/support/maps-pano/index.html).